# Select - options and AngularJS - add glyphicon to options

Tags: angularjs, select, glyphicons

I use this select - options in my AngularJS application:

```
<select data-ng-model="userFilter" data-ng-options="c as c.firstname + ' ' + c.surname for c in vm.users">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

and now I will add a glyphicon to each option value:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

is there a possibility to do it like this?

Comment: it's possible to do so using button dropdown of bootstrap which uses `ul` and `li`s.. even if you find an approach using `select`s it would be dirty

Comment: Try use `ng-repeat`  instead of `ng-options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way with ng-options, though you could use ng-repeat:

```
<select data-ng-model="userFilterIndex" data-ng-change ="userFilter = vm.users[ userFilterIndex ]">

    <option data-ng-repeat="c in vm.users" value="{{ $index }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        {{ c.firstname + ' ' + c.surname }}
    </option>

</select>
```