# glyphicon on AngularJS Dynamic Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I am creating a web app in which i have a dropdown which looks like this

```
<select id="passengerCountDropDown" ng-change="reselectpassengerCount()" ng-options="passanger.Name for passanger in passangers" ng-model="passengerCountArray"></select>
```

and this is how i am filling the data

```
scope.passangers = [{ Name: "Passanger 1", Value: 1 }];
var totalPassangers = 21;
for (var i = 2; i <= totalPassangers; i++) {
    scope.passangers.push({ "Name": "Passanger" + " " + i, "Value": i });
}
scope.passengerCountArray = scope.passangers[0];
scope.passengerCount = scope.passangers[0].Value;
```

now the problem is, i want to add glyphicon on the options in the dropdown but i am not able to do this,

i also Tried from another example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109309/select-options-and-angularjs-add-glyphicon-to-options)

but did not succeed

```
    <select ng-model="passengerCountArray">
        <option ng-repeat="c in passangers" value="{{ $index }}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            {{ c.Name }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Here is my JSfiddle
[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/dq8r196v/675/)

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select - options and AngularJS - add glyphicon to options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109309/select-options-and-angularjs-add-glyphicon-to-options)

Answer (score 0):

i think this can be ur answer:

http://thewebfosters.com/add-icons-html-select-options/

or you can simulate a select tag by your own like what they did in angular material.

Comment: Updated my question